# Reactivating Recurly subscription

Tags: c#, recurly

I'm trying to reactivate a previously cancelled account using the Recurly .NET client.

I've tried using the Create method but it throws an already_subscribed error so instead I've tried Subscription.Reactivate. This reactivates the subscription but it doesn't associate the billing info with the subscription.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Was the account closed as part of the original cancelation? If so, the billing information was deleted and cannot be restored.

Also, your original error was because the subscription was still active (just in the canceled state). You can use the Create call after the subscription is terminated, OR, you can enable multiple subscriptions per account.

Comment: Yes it was closed using Accounts.Close() so yes the account is closed, subscription cancelled and billing information deleted. I've used GetSubscriptions() to get the subscription and then Terminate() to delete it and then created again. Is that the right way to do it? Or should I somehow associate billing info to the subscription and then use subscription.Reactivate()? Thanks

Comment: Also when cancelling an account we deactivate them so they cannot log in any more so is there anything wrong with terminating the subscription at that point?

Comment: Generally I don't recommend closing accounts since clearing billing information is so permanent. You may just want to consider canceling/terminating.